# Reading log files

Tags: logging, .net-core, asp.net-web-api2, log4net, nlog

I am currently developing a .Net Core solution which consists of multiple WebAPI applications talk to each other. Each application has it's own logging set up (currently I am using NLog).

Each application also needs to be able to send it's logs to a UI so users can see when things stop working. For this, I thought of building a simple Controller which handles this. However, I am stuck on how to actually read the logs. All I have found so far are posts describing how to read logs using external log viewers, not through code itself.

So is there some package or logging framework that can read log files generated by NLog this? I am not bound to NLog by the way, so I could also use other logging frameworks for .Net Core.

Comment: Did you consider to set up some other targets? You could use a db-target to log into one db. This way you can easily read your logs, if asked by a UI. In your case a Log-target which calls an web-api to perform the logging could be reasonable. This api could also provide access to your logs for UIs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [WebService target](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/WebService-target) in order to call a web service on each log message, so you can centralize all events. Then you can save events in a DB or wherever you want, and of course, read them to show in the UI.

Also, read [this article](https://stackify.com/nlog-guide-dotnet-logging/) about bests practices with NLog.

Answer (score 1):

There are known applications like FileBeat and ElasticSearch that will provide Web-Access to your log-files.